# How can I add Subtitles to ToC with ExSheets?

Tags: table-of-contents, exsheets

I know how to add questions to the Table of Contents using `exsheets` key `questions-totoc`.

I would like the Table of Contents to have question subtitles, so my students (and I) know what the questions are about at a glance.

How can I add subtitles to the ToC?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\SetupExSheets{
    headings=block-subtitle,
    questions-totoc=true,
    question/name=Question
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{question}[subtitle=Gradient Vector]
\end{question}

\begin{question}[subtitle=Optimization]
\end{question}

\begin{question}[subtitle=Optimization with Constraints]
\end{question}

\begin{question}[subtitle={Proving Second Derivative Test for $f(x,y)$}]
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

One idea I had was to use `\IfQuestionSubtitleTF` to conditionally add to the current ToC line. However, I don't know how to add to the *current* ToC line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\def\questionName{Question}

\SetupExSheets{
    headings=block-subtitle,
    %questions-totoc=true,
    question/name=\questionName
}
\newcommand{\QtoToC}[2]{
    \begin{question}[subtitle=#1]
     #2
     \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\questionName\space\thequestion. \emph{#1}}
    \end{question}
    }

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \QtoToC{Gradient Vector}
         {} % <- the Q body goes here

    \QtoToC{Optimization}
         {}

    \QtoToC{Optimization with Constraints}
         {}

    \QtoToC{{Proving Second Derivative Test for $f(x,y)$}}
         {}

    \QtoToC{}% Q without subtitle
         {}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

**Edit:**

Based on his comment, this is what I think @clemens would use: :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\def\questionName{Question}

\SetupExSheets{
    headings=block-subtitle,
    question/name=\questionName,
    question/pre-hook = \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{
        \questionName\space\thequestion. \IfQuestionSubtitleT{\emph{\GetQuestionProperty{subtitle}{\CurrentQuestionID}}}
        }
    }

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \begin{question}[subtitle=Gradient Vector]
    \end{question}

    \begin{question}[subtitle=Optimization]
    \end{question}

    \begin{question}[subtitle=Optimization with Constraints]
    \end{question}

    \begin{question}[subtitle={Proving Second Derivative Test for $f(x,y)$}]
    \end{question}

     \begin{question}
     \end{question}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd rather use the question hooks instead of putting the environment in a new macro...

Comment: @clemens I edited my answer to include your suggestion, thanks. I admit I tend to hide repeating environment calls (saves screen real estate & highlight distraction => "concentrate on the content").

Comment: Are you saying you never use environments (which not only are core construct of LaTeX but also *do* serve a very good purpose having semantics in mind)?

Comment: @clemens No, I just hide them in macros (if possible) if I have to call them too often (dozens times) - as the OP MWE suggests.

Comment: Thanks both. I certainly prefer the hook version ... I'd rather use `question` as the environment, to make questions easier to reuse between different `exsheets` documents.

Comment: @alwaysask Instead of `\thequestion.` I'd probably use `\GetQuestionProperty{counter}{\CurrentQuestionID}`. I'd also put the space between number and subtitle inside of `\IfQuestionSubtitleT`